# Running a remote binary via a bash script is hanging if I give certain command line args

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to run a remote binary in a couple different hosts from a script, it makes sense to be able to kick off each of them in their respective hosts and just wait for all of those remote ssh commands before exiting. My attempt to do that is something like this:

```
for host in A B C
do
    ssh user@$host "
    function test
    {
        cd /path/to/foo
        ./foo_exe --optA > run.out 2>&1
    }; test &
done

wait
```

Unfortunately this seems to run sequentially, running first on host A, then on B etc..why is this not being deployed at the same time on each host?

Comment: The title doesn't seem to reflect post content, isn't it?

Comment: You're missing the closing quotation mark, presumably before the ampersand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test` process is holding open `stdout` and `stderr`, even though `foo_exe` redirects them. `ssh` won't finish till these are closed. The simplest thing is to redirect them:

```
for host in A B C
do
    ssh user@$host '
    function test
    {
        cd /path/to/foo
        ./foo_exe --optA > run.out 2>&1
    }; test > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
done
```

More specifically, the `sshd` process on the remote server that your ssh connects to spawns a shell process and listens for writes to the pipes associated with stdout/stderr so it can forward them back across the network to your local ssh.  It keeps listening until it gets an end-of-file notification on the pipes and then it shuts down the link.  It only receives the end-of-file notification when there are no processes left that have the pipes open for output.  This is standard behaviour for pipes.  (It's more complicated than that: there's a bunch of virtual terminal magic going on but I'm not sure exactly how that works: I'd have to look it up.)

Backgrounding `ssh` as suggested by barmar will leave you with a number of `ssh` processes on your local machine waiting for the remote ends to finish, whereas with my method, the ssh finishes immediately.

Comment: awesome never would have thought this was the case!

Answer (score 1):

Put the `ssh` command in the background, not the remote command.

```
for host in A B C
do
    ssh user@$host "
    function test
    {
        cd /path/to/foo
        ./foo_exe --optA > run.out 2>&1
    }; test" &
done

wait
```

The reason is that `ssh` is waiting for the server to close the network connection before it exits. It doesn't go into the background just because the remote command is in the background.

BTW, have you heard of `pssh`?

http://www.theether.org/pssh/